# Can I select all attributes except for one in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Say I want to load a bunch of `Foo` records, but I only want to load the `id` and `title` attributes into memory:

```
foos = Foo.where([condition]).select('id, title')
```

What if I want to load all attributes EXCEPT for one (i.e. because it's giant text column)? You know, something like:

```
foos = Foo.where([condition]).select('* except giant_text_dump')
```

Obviously that doesn't work. But is there a way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this?

```
Foo.where([condition]).select(*Foo.attribute_names.reject { |attr| attr == 'giant_text_dump' })
```

Comment: Yeah... I ended up going with something like this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

ActiveRecord doesn't have a way to do that built in, but you can do this:

```
fields = (Foo.attribute_names - ['giant_text_dump']).join(',')
Foo.where([condition]).select(fields)
```